# Is the set of triangles closed?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, measure-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of simple polygons in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with strictly positive area.

Define the distance between any two such polygons, say $A$ and $B$, to be $d(A,B) = \mu(A \Delta B)$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $A \Delta B = (A - B) \cup(B-A)$ is the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$. The distance function $d$ makes $\mathcal{P}$ a metric space.

Let $\mathcal{T}$ denote the set of all triangles in $\mathcal{P}$.

Is $\mathcal{T}$ a closed subset of $\mathcal{P}$?

### My attempt

When need to show if $T_n \in \mathcal{T}$ is such that there is a $P_0$ in $\mathcal{P}$ such that $d(T_n,P_0) \to 0$ then $P_0 \in \mathcal{T}$.

Since $|\mu(T_n) - \mu(P_0)| \leq d(T_n,P_0)$ this also means $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(T_n) = \mu(P_0) > 0$.

Let $x_n,y_n,z_n$ denote the vertices of $T_n$ in some order, then ***if*** we can show the $T_n$'s are uniformly bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ then, passing to a subsequence if necessary, we can assume wlog that $x_n,y_n,z_n$ converges to (say) $x_0,y_0,z_0$. Let $T_0$ be the (possibly degenerate) triangle described by $x_0,y_0,z_0$, then it is sufficient to show $d(T_n,T_0) \to 0$ and $T_0$ is not degenerate.

We have, $d(T_n,T_0) = \mu(T_n) + \mu(T_0) - 2\mu(T_n \cap T_0)$.
Clearly $\mu(T_n) \to \mu(T_0)$. This also shows $\mu(T_0) > 0$ and so $T_0$ is not degenerate.

And we also have, $\mu(T_n \cap T_0) = \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^2}I_{T_n}(x)I_T(x)dx$ (where $I_A()$ is the indicator function of the set $A$). We can show $I_{T_n}(x) \to 1$ whenever $x$ is an interior point of $T_0$ and $I_{T_n}(x) \to 0$ for $x \not\in T_0$, this is sufficient to show, using DCT, $\mu(T_n \cap T_0) \to \mu(T_0)$ and we are done.

So we need to show $T_n$'s are uniformly bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Arthur updated with a description of my attempt.

Comment: My gut says it's easier to show that the complement is open.

Comment: $\mathcal P$ is not a *complete* metric space with respect to $d$, if I'm not wrong. In fact, $\mathcal T$ is not closed with respect to $d$. Therefore, one must use the structure of $P_0$ to move forward.

Comment: If the polygons are allowed to have coincident vertices then the set of triangles is obviously not closed. If the polygons don't have coincident vertices then how is that defined?

Comment: @SuzuHirose The condition that the polygons need to have positive volume rules out degenerate cases.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri Depending on the definition of polygon you're using it might not rule out a triangle shaped tetragon with two coincident vertices, or triangle shaped tetragons which have three collinear vertices, as both would still have a positive volume.

Comment: We restrict ourselves to simple polygons. Vertices are where edges meet, and two consecutive parallel edges are ruled out.

Comment: I guess the requirement of simple polygons of positive area also excludes the case of a sequence of triangles getting "thinner and thinner" and approaching a line segment as a limit.

Comment: @DanielSchepler  Yes, that is right.

Comment: However, I suppose that almost-counterexample does point out: in the attempted proof, you would also need to show that $x_0, y_0, z_0$ are distinct and not collinear in order to form $T_0$, and that's also not immediately obvious.

Comment: @DanielSchepler That happens because from $d(T_n,P_0) \to 0$ we can show $\mu(T_n) \to \mu(P_0) > 0$.   Then since $\mu(T_n) \to \mu(T_0)$ we also must have $\mu(T_0) > 0$.

Comment: I think the answer is yes (although I have no proof) and that @Arthur is right. It would boil down to show that if $P$ has at least $4$ vertices, then there exists some $\varepsilon >0$ such that any polygon $P'$ with $d(P,P') <\varepsilon$ has at least $4$ vertices. This seems intuitive with a drawing, but I have no time to spend right now on this

Comment: In fact, after reading your attempt, I think this should work. To show that $T_n$ is uniformly bounded, let $p_0 \in P_0$, $d= \mathrm{diam} P_0$ and $M = \sup_{n}d(T_n,P_0)$. Then we should have something like $T_n \subset B(p_0; d+M)$ or an adaptation of this ?

Comment: Any thought about the answer? Did you understand it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is positive. Indeed, suppose that $T_n=A_nB_nC_n$ is a sequence of triangles of unbounded size which converges (in your sense) to a polygon $P$. Then the sequence of areas of $T_n$'s converges to the area of $P$. WLOG, we can assume that the distances $|A_nB_n|$ diverge to infinity. Then the sequence of heights $h_n$ of $T_n$'s (with respect to the base $A_nB_n$) has to converge to zero (otherwise, areas will diverge to infinity). Let $S_n$ denote the parallel strip in the plane $E^2$ which is bounded by the infinite line $(A_nB_n)$ and the parallel line through $C_n$. Thus, $h_n$ is the width of $S_n$ and $T_n\subset S_n$.

Lemma. For every compact $K\subset E^2$  the areas of $T_n\cap K$ converge to zero.

Proof. It suffices to prove the claim for compacts $K$ of the form $B=B(R)$, the closed disk of radius $R$ centered at the origin in $E^2$.  Clearly, the area of $T_n\cap B$ is at most the area of $S_n\cap B$. The latter is at most $2Rh_n$, which converges to zero as $n\to\infty$. qed

Now, we can finish the proof. Take $K=P$. By your notion of convergence $T_n\to P$,  it follows that the areas of $T_n\cap P$ converge to the area of $P$  as $n\to\infty$. By Lemma, this limit equals zero. Hence, $P$ has zero area, contradicting your definition of a polygon.